# How can eliminate the migration error in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

When I try to migrate I get an error:
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration posty.0038_remove_post_uzytkownik_post_grupa dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0048_alter_group_grupa_departament_and_more')

Deleting folders **pycache** and migrations doesn't help

Please help.

Deleting folders **pycache** and migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posty/migrations/0038_remove_post_uzytkownik_post_grupa.py` expects that `auth/migrations/0048_alter_group_grupa_departament_and_more.py` exists.

In my experience, this is often caused because whoever created posty.0038... also created auth.0048...., and forgot to add auth.0048... to the code repository.